# How to change value for NLS_CHARACTERSET

Tags: oracle12c

in Oralce 12, can I change the NLS_CHARACTERSET value without having to take a backup.

```
 Query: SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters;
 Result: NLS_CHARACTERSET
         WE8MSWIN1252
```

I want to change it to

```
 AL32UTF8
```

Comment: What do you mean "without having to take a backup"?  You can use the Database Migration Assistant for Unicode (DMU) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/globalization/dmu/overview/index.html to convert the database to Unicode.  But you really, really, really want to have a solid backup before you do that-- it is a huge change that will probably require changes to applications.

Comment: I see. I am not a database person at all. I got this request to change the characterset value on one of the boxes I maintain. When I googled, it looked like it involves a lot of DB activities. So wondered if that can be done through a sql query. Thanks for the response.

Comment: You can probably find a post somewhere that has a query that directly updates the data dictionary.  !!!DO NOT DO THIS!!!  This was an old, old, old, old vaguely supported way of changing a database character set from the Oracle 7 days that kind of worked if you understood all the implications of what you are doing.  It comes up rather often in Google searches though.

Comment: Thank you. I read documents and understand the risk of it.

Comment: I hope you are not saying that you are planning on doing a direct data dictionary update.  Particularly without a solid backup and a plan to recover when your system gets trashed.

Comment: No am not.  I wanted to try by myself if that is going to be as simple as running a query. Since it is not the case, I am approaching some DBA help here. Thanks!